# Regex for a valid month

Tags: regex, directive

I am using following directive for making an input text box numeric only. But, how should I change the regex so it allows entering numbers only between 1 and 12 (both inclusive).

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
    .module("xyz")
    .directive('numericOnly', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                function fromUser(text) {
                    if (text) {
                        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                        if (transformedInput !== text) {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                            ngModelCtrl.$render();
                        }
                        return transformedInput;
                    }
                    return undefined;
                }
                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            }
        };
    })
}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(1[012]|[1-9])$
```

Here it has actually two regex are piped (or). First one is matching `10-12` and second one is matching `1-9`. In total `1-12`.

Comment: Adding a leading zero `^(1[012]|0?[1-9])$` is allowing month to be specified as `01`,`02`, which might be helpful

Comment: I would not explain it as *it has actually two regex are piped (or)*. `|` is an alternation operator here and is used to separate *alternative subpatterns*.

Comment: But, I need to negate the expression to use in text.replace(Negative_pattern, ''). How can I negate the pattern?
I am using (?! ^(1[012]|[1-9])$) but its not working.

Comment: @CodeZila  Not sure, may be something like this can help you  `^(?!(1[012]|[1-9])$).*$`